# Delay and low speed in loading iframe content at huge visit

Tags: php, performance, iframe

Working on a system which will store more than `4 million` records `per day`.
To reduce I/O and increase speed I change the storage from database to file. So data will change to json and directly written to file.

---

### More Info

The system is `ppc` system written by PHP which show banner in several sites with their own servers through an iframe.

whenever this banner load in any site, I'll store one record of it's info in file (was an insert to database before) and update tow fields in tow tables in database.

---

### Issue

When visits go up and reach almost 3000 visit per minute, iframe loading speed reduce significantly, further more sometimes cause printing server timeout in iframe.

I'm looking for ways to reduce resource using and increasing loading speed and also preventing timeout.

Any help will be highly appreciated...

Comment: What is that slows your server? Banner images? Are you sure that is fastest changing database to a file?  Have you any compression system in your apache? Have you got a programatically buffer in your php? Sorry, but with this information I can't help you more.

Comment: Maybe this links are helpful to you: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-optimize-apache-web-server-performance    |   http://www.giftofspeed.com/apache-server/

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude thanks for answer, changing database to file at least make my read/write better and decrease storage using, and as I measure there is no significant change in time in the range  that I face. And as I know there is no compression system available on my server

Comment: Read and write files with PHP needs more resources from server to execute than a MySQL database. Maybe you reduce the input/output stream, but the processor and RAM of your server maybe it's full

Comment: Where you host system? If you are using hosting company, it might be some hosting plan limits. (e.g. bandwidth limit, etc.)

Comment: @user2988142 no it's dedicated and there is no limit

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude you're right but the same issue was exist before switch to file

Comment: I don't know if you can, but if yes you can put here the dedicated server's specifications. And if you can access through SSH with root, maybe you can monitoring what is the problem (RAM, HDD, Processor, etc). I recommend to you to activate the apache cache module. This caching all your content (including images) and reduces the time of processing. Compress images, minimize CSS, HTML and Javascript files and reduce the size of PHP files helps you to speedup. If you don't have fast-cgi for php maybe it's better if you activate it.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude really I appreciate your helps, I'll tell our server administrator to do these and as soon as possible I'll list the specification here.

Comment: Ok, I wait for it. Tomorrow I came here to view if you update the post. Maybe your server's administrator is interested in know good options to buy dedicated servers, like http://esquio.net/clientes/cart.php?gid=2 (it is administrated by me) and the prizes are so good, with **1Gbps of connection speed**. Good luck :)

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude of course, thanks ;)

Comment: BTW, if data is structured, no need to use json, which is wasteful on storage. You can use a csv instead

Comment: have you thought about using memcached to store things, instead of writing to files?

Comment: @RobGudgeon thanks for answer. As I know memcache is temporary storage tools but I need something continual.

Comment: @HosseinShahsahebi yep, I was more thinking that you could avoid disk I/O by storing things there instead of a DB or file, in case the disk I/O is what's holding things up. You'd still need a cronjob to retrieve the items from memcached & store them permanently, of course, but it may reduce your bottleneck. 

Also, just a thought - if this is running on Apache, have you checked or modified MaxClients, in case it's just that all your httpd processes are in use & requests are being backed up waiting for a free process? Haven't read all the answers or your responses, so this may be irrelevant :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With 3k requests a minute, and with hope of growth, you need to start utilizing `big data` architecture and tools.

Here are some broad picture highlights to consider:

- Use a seperate `CDN` to store and serve the images.
- Use `mapReduce` software to store the data, such as [hadoop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Hadoop).
- Get servers which are `distributed`, as opposed to one huge server.
- Add a `load balancing` server.
- Turn off all php features & extensions you don't need.

Comment: Thanks for answer, It seems to be a good answer but also seems to need very deep and structural changes in existing project. I consider this as a good answer but let me to make question open for others to answer and finally I'll make a decision.

Answer (score 4):

At this particular point in the size of your application I would focus on two specific improvements to your infrastructure and code logic.

1. Decouple the processes needed to serve banner assets to the end user from the processes needed to store ad impressions.
2. Implement a horizontally scalable infrastructure for receiving requests.

### 1. Decoupling serving banners from storing impressions

By separating these two concerns you will be able to provide more consistent performance for the customers of your `ppc` service. If you aren't already, using a CDN or otherwise offloading the demand of serving the images themselves from your severs can help improve response time considerably.

Another area that will give you large gains is separating the serving of banner code from the processes that store the impression data to disk. There are a number of ways to do this, but a successful solution I have had experience with is utilizing ActiveMQ (http://activemq.apache.org/) or a similar queuing system. A queuing system will help balance your impression storage load over time by storing impression data in memory and sending off those data points at a consistent rate to consumer (aka worker) processes that can store that data into a DB or other storage medium. This allows the workload of actually storing impressions on disk to be separated from the process of serving ads. You can also set up multiple processes to consume the queued up jobs, which leads to the second area of improvement.

### 2. Horizontally scalable infrastructure

Building a horizontally scalable solution basically means that instead of needing to increase the size and power of a single server, you can just add additional smaller servers that will evenly share the workload of the system demands. This has multiple advantages, one of which being it is easier (and usually cheaper) to add a few more small servers to a pool rather than upgrading one big server to be larger and more powerful. It also had the advantage of being more robust in the event that a server fails.

In this case I think a good solution would be to have one server or process acting as a router, which will just load balance requests by sending them off to different servers that are doing the actual processing of the request. There are a lot of good resources about building routing or load balancing scripts in PHP out there on the internet, but basically you will receive requests at one endpoint, and then send that request to a different server to actually be fulfilled. If you build a dynamic list of servers that are ready to receive requests then you can easily increase the number of servers fulfilling requests when your start to see unacceptable performance. This will also give you the benefit of being able to easily remove a server from the list if it goes down, and then any traffic would just get routed to a different server that was still up.

If you haven't already, it would be good to look into lighttpd (http://www.lighttpd.net/) or nginx (https://www.nginx.com/) as alternatives to Apache which are built to be able to handle large volumes of requests with less overhead. These would be especially well suited to handling the requests on your router server.

Once you have horizontal scaling set up for requests, it would be fairly simply to set up horizontal scaling for storage servers as well. You can easily do this by modding an ID by the number of servers in the pool to determine where to send the request.

```
$serverNumber = $adID % $availableServers;
```

### Summary

Although you can definitely see good performance improvements by optimizing storage methods and server tuning, at some point in a large application you will want to be able to add additional servers to get the job done. I think with the above steps you will be in a very good place to scale your application smoothly as it grows in size.

Comment: First of all I'm so grateful of your detail description. Somehow it was the detail of tow most important option which `Skarlinski` offers in his answer. After these words I have to ask something about load balancing. As you said, one server will be the router. Now this server will be the bottleneck of system and same issue will raise up. Am I correct?

Comment: The benefit of this setup is how it separates responsibilities and delegates them to be handled by different processes. The router server is only responsible for directing requests, so it should be able to handle enough traffic to keep a number of DB and ad servers busy. You can look into http level load balancing if you get to the point of needing multiple router servers to handle your traffic. A couple options for that are a dedicated nginx server (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/load_balancing.html), or more cheaply (with some drawbacks) using DNS load balancing.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to save on both performance and development hours by leveraging your existing Apache access logging to act as your impression tracker, and completely turn off your custom database/flat-file read/write code.

Set up a new Apache virtual host, and point it to a system webroot directory that you will make solely responsible for serving up your ad-generation PHP script. Within this one virtual host configuration, you can set up a system access log which is 100% exclusive to serving your ads; Apache will take care of appending to this log upon every visit (impression) and rotating/archiving the log as needed. You can point to wherever you would like to store the log as well as what kind of server/environment/referrer/user-agent data gets stored to it.

Then, via cron or a daemon, you can run whatever back-end log analyzer you would like, gather statistics into a database, crunch your numbers, etc, without coupling any of this heavier lifting to live web requests.

I also found on Stack Overflow the suggestion to use this technique [with lighttpd instead of Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1428731/best-practices-tracking-banner-impressions) to further stretch your server resources.

**Further reading:**

- [Clever Impression Tracking Technique](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/267181)
- [Apache: Log Files](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/logs.html)
- [lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/)